# HTML get value from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to crunch my head on how to accomplish this:

I'm following this method from w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_variables_create

The HTML and Javascript is seperate.
Is it possible to get the value from the javascript variable upon loading and update it as the variable decreases?

HTML:

```
<span id="myField"></span>
```

JS:

```
var counter= 5;
document.getElementById("myField").innerHTML = counter;
```

I've attached the javascript by using this method:

```
<script src="lib/game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've been getting this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at game.js:15

Line 15 :

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter;
```

Comment: Welp, is there an element with an ID "demo"?

Comment: Firstly, the ID's don't match. Secondly, the script file has to go **after** the element in the DOM

Comment: @adeneo, the first one due to bad pasting. So i have to call in the HTML itself rather than putting it in the separate script?

Comment: No, you can put the javascript in a separate file, but that file has to be included **after** the element you're trying to access or you'll need a DOM ready handler. Try placing the script right before the closing `</body>`

Comment: It should be - document.getElementById("myField"). Thank you !

Comment: @adeneo, you're a genius man !! it worked

Comment: @adeneo, could you put it as an answer so i can give a correct also.. I'm curious regarding the DOM ready handler. As i need to reduce the counter and update the HTML

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of many other, so I'll just tag it as such !

Comment: @adeneo, seriously? damn i've been googling the wrong keyword then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var counter= 5;
document.getElementById("myField").innerHTML = counter;
```

```html
<span id="myField"></span>
```

Actually this run in Snippet

Comment: my bad, i copied it wrongly. updated it already

Comment: Yeah, the thing the `document.getElementById("myField").innerHTML = counter;` is separate and it's not called the html.

Comment: Actually there is no error in this code, ERROR says , cannot set property value, you are setting innerHTML, so the error is in some other DOM element